# Wrong type when searching from enum in collection in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, enums, jpa-2.0, criteria

My class `Role` has a property `enumP` which is :

```
@Convert(converter = EnumPConverter.class)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private EnumP enumP;
```

This is the converter :

```
@Converter(autoApply = false)
public class EnumPConverter implements AttributeConverter<EnumP, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final EnumP attribute) {
        switch (attribute) {
        case X:
            return "X";
        case Y:
            return "Y";
        case Z:
            return "Z";
        default:
            throw new DbException("Type of enumeration is unknown at the time of conversion to a DB value.",
                    new IllegalArgumentException("Value received : " + attribute));
        }
    }


    @Override
    public EnumP convertToEntityAttribute(final String dbData) {
        switch (dbData) {
        case "X":
            return EnumP.X;
        case "Y":
            return EnumP.Y;
        case "Z":
            return EnumP.Z;
        default:
            throw new DbException("Unknown enumerated value was found in the DB",
                    new IllegalArgumentException("Value received : " + dbData));
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the Enum :

```
public enum EnumP {
    X, Y, Z;
}
```

When the predicate is:

```
builder.isTrue(fromRole.get(Role_.enumP).in((Object[]) filter.getFilterSetValues()))
```

Where `getFilterSetValues()` will return a String array as following:

```
["X", "Y"]
```

I get the following exception :

```
Parameter value [X] did not match expected type [EnumP (n/a)]
```

I tried to add a line breakpoint on the converter but the debugger doesn't stop in that line.

***PS : I have no right to modify in the `Enum` so any manipulation should be done inside the converter.***

Comment: You meant `@Convert(converter = EnumPConverter.class)`, right?

Comment: @crizzis yes sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

Why use a converter if you have the same values X->X, Y->Y, Z->Z ?
I think `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` is suffisant in your case, no need to convert them.

i'm agree with @crizzis it's a bad practice to use string value of an enum. the better is to implement your getFilterSetValues to return an array of enump values

Comment: @AimadMAJDOU Alternatively, drop the `@Enumerated` altogether. Don't use both. The javadocs for `@Converter` state that: 'The Convert annotation should not be used to specify conversion of the following: Id attributes, version attributes, relationship attributes, and **attributes explicitly denoted as Enumerated** or Temporal'

Comment: Yes, indeed, as I said the converter doesn't work in the first place, since the debugger doesn't stop on any breakpoit inside the converter as I montioned, but still I get that exception, since `fromRole.get(Role_.enumProvenanceID)` will return an enum value which can't be compared to string values in `filter.getFilterSetValues()`

Comment: Thanks, but `fromRole.get(Role_.enumP)` will return a `Path` which has no `name` function

Answer (score 0):

Since `Role.enumP` is of type `EnumP` while `getFilterSetValues()` returns an array of strings, there is an obvious type mismatch. You need to pass an array of `EnumP` to the `in()` method instead.

Comment: That what I thought, but then I have to create some sort of a function inside `EnumP`  which will take the `getFilterSetValues()` and then retruns an array of `EnumP`, but since I don't have the right to modify the `EnumP`, the best way is to convert  `fromRole.get(Role_.enumP)` to a String value instead of converting the received String array.

Comment: JPA won't do that for you. You yourself decided to treat `Role.enumP` as an enum (and not a string) by mapping it accordingly. If you need `Role.enumP` as a string, map it as a string, otherwise use enums everywhere.

Comment: Also, I don't understand what you mean by 'I have to create some sort of a function inside `EnumP` which will take the `getFilterSetValues()` and then retruns an array of `EnumP`' - why does the converting method have to go into `EnumP`? And maybe a more pertinent question - why is `getFilterSetValues()` operating on an array of strings in the first place?

Comment: So there is no way I can convert `fromRole.get(Role_.enumP)` to a String value ? what about if I did something like this : `fromRole.<String> get("enumProvenanceID")`, and for your second question, because I use  `EnumP` with other entities and not only `Role`.

Comment: see my answer fromRole.get(Role_.enumP).name()

Comment: @FrançoisLEPORCQ I don't think there is a `name()` method on the `Expression` interface that `Root.get()` returns. @AimadMAJDOU, what is `enumProvenanceID`? Unless there is a string property `enumProvenanceID` in the `Role` entity, the type mismatch still persists.

Comment: I was thinking that fromRole.get(Role_.enumP) was returning an enum instance sorry

Comment: @AimadMAJDOU BTW, there is a conversion method already implemented in `EnumP`. It's called `EnumP.valueOf`. That being said, making `getFilterSetValues()` operate on string values is still a bad practice. The whole point of using an enum is making sure the values are limited to a predefined set. How does the same validation logic not apply to the array returned from `getFilterSetValues()`?

Comment: @crizzis The arrray returned from `getFilterSetValues()` will contain string values, since I get them from a Rest method, the front end application will send those values as strings.

Comment: yes but you can use the method valueOf to retrieve you enum value from a string

Comment: Well then the array should be converted to an array of enums way before it reaches the data persistence layer, probably by your controller. This way, malformed requests will not be bounced back immediately without the performance penalty of querying the database unnecessarily.

Comment: could you post your getFilterSetValues() method please @Aimad MAJDOU

Comment: Sorry, What I meant to say was that malformed requests **will be** bounced back immediately. I can't edit my comment anymore

Comment: @FrançoisLEPORCQ I think I'll just convert the array in the controller